# SQL: partition over two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have following table:

```
---------------------
| No1 | No2  | Amount
---------------------
| A   |  B   |    10 |
| C   |  D   |    20 |
| B   |  A   |    30 |
| D   |  C   |    40 |
---------------------
```

and I want to sum over partition by both columns (No1,No2) but it should group also when the values are changed in the two columns. Example would be: AB = BA

This would be my expected result:

```
-----------------------------------------
| No1 | No2  | Sum(Amount) over partition
-----------------------------------------
| A   |  B   |    40                    |
| C   |  D   |    60                    |
| B   |  A   |    40                    |
| D   |  C   |    60                    |
-----------------------------------------
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the values ever `NULL`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no the values are never NULL

Comment: . . There are no "next questions" that are added as edits.  You should accept Vamsi's answer and ask *another* question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `least` and `greatest`.

```
select no1,no2,sum(amount) over(partition by least(no1,no2),greatest(no1,no2)) as total
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

```
WITH test_data AS
(
SELECT 'A' no1, 'B' no2, 10 amt FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'D', 20 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'A', 30 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'C', 40 FROM dual
)
SELECT NVL(no1, break_group) no1, no2, total --, grp1, grp2, break_group 
  FROM
(
SELECT no1, no2, total
     , grouping(no1) grp1
     , grouping(no2) grp2
     , LAG(no1, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY total ORDER BY no1)||LAG(no1) OVER (PARTITION BY total ORDER BY no1) break_group
  FROM
( -- Vamsi Prabhala query --
select no1, no2
     , sum(amt) over(partition by least(no1,no2),greatest(no1,no2)) as total
from test_data
)
GROUP BY ROLLUP (total, no1, no2)
HAVING grouping(no1) + grouping(no2) = 0
OR grouping(no1) + grouping(no2) = 2
AND total IS NOT NULL
)
/
```

Output - you can replace nulls (empty) with any vlue:

```
|NO1 |  NO2  | Total
----------------------
A        B      40
B        A      40
AB              40
C        D      60
D        C      60
CD              60
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem with your SQL is that there can be multiple rows with the same No1 and No2 values.. please see my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174587/sql-insert-rows-with-summarized-values

Comment: And? Who stopped you create multiple rows in your example? And who said the ROLLUP will not work in such case? And I do not care about scores here. These are the same grouping sets  different way.