# SQL: insert rows with summarized values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, grouping

please see my first question to my topic: [SQL: partition over two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044809/sql-partition-over-two-columns)

I have following table:

```
----------------------------------
| No1 | No2  | Amount| Timestamp
----------------------------------
| A   |  B   |    10 |  01.01.2018
| C   |  D   |    20 |  02.01.2018
| B   |  A   |    30 |  03.01.2018
| D   |  C   |    40 |  04.01.2018
----------------------------------
```

I have the following results at the moment:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| No1 | No2  | Sum(Amount) over partition | Timestamp
-----------------------------------------------------
| A   |  B   |    40                      | 01.01.2018
| C   |  D   |    60                      | 02.01.2018
| B   |  A   |    40                      | 03.01.2018
| D   |  C   |    60                      | 04.01.2018
-----------------------------------------------------
```

with the SQL (from the first question with Vamsi Prabhala's answer):

```
select no1,no2,sum(amount) over(partition by least(no1,no2),greatest(no1,no2)) as total, timestamp
from tbl
```

The question for me now is how can I add rows to the results like:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| No1 | No2  | Sum(Amount) over partition | Timestamp
----------------------------------------------------
| A   |  B   |    40  (optional)          | 01.01.2018
| B   |  A   |    40  (optional)          | 02.01.2018
| AB  |(NULL)|    40                      |
| C   |  D   |    60  (optional)          | 03.01.2018
| D   |  C   |    60  (optional)          | 04.01.2018
| CD  |(NULL)|    60                      |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Please be aware that there can be multiple rows with for example the values (No1=A,No2=B)

UPDATE: added timestamp column to be more specific what I want to achieve

Comment: Do you really want to add those rows to a `table`???  Or just write a query to return those example results?  Also, why do you want three rows for each combination?  *(Wouldn't your `AB, NULL, 40` and `CD, NULL, 60` rows be sufficient?  What are the other rows telling you?)*

Comment: @MatBailie sry for the confussion.. I want to get this as a result and not insert the rows in a table. I need the other rows because there are some other relevant columns for each No1-No2 row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  LEAST(No1, No2) || ':' || GREATEST(No1, No2)     AS set_label,
  No1,
  No2,
  SUM(Amount)                               AS Amount,
  Stamp
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  GROUPING SETS (
    (LEAST(No1, No2), GREATEST(No1, No2), No1, No2, Stamp),
    (LEAST(No1, No2), GREATEST(No1, No2))
  )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9afd5/18

Would be better if each row has a unique identifier...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9e95/1

Comment: I need the other rows because there are some other columns like timestamp for each row.. I will update the question to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

One method is `UNION ALL`:

```
select no1, no2,
       sum(amount) over (partition by least(no1, no2), greatest(no1, no2)) as total
from tbl
union all
select least(no1, no2) || greatest(no1, no2), NULL, sum(amount)
from tbl
group by least(no1, no2), greatest(no1, no2);
```